# twitter4j getPlaceTrends returns 50 top trends instead of 10

Tags: java, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I have this piece of code in the run method of my class `TrendsReader`

```
Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(1);

for (Trend tr : trends.getTrends()) {
   synchronized(lock){
       activeTrends.put(tr, new Date(dateRepresentation.getTime()));
   }
}

if(reader == null){ //start getting the tweets
 TwitterStream stream = new TwitterStreamFactory(conf).getInstance();
 reader = new TweetsReader(lock, activeTrends, stream, db);
 reader.start();
}
```

In my main I create a configuration with my access tokens and a Twitter instance is given in `TrendsReader`'s constructor.

The thing is, the method `getPlaceTrends` returns 50 trends, instead of 10. This code used to work perfectly when I wrote it and now a couple of months later I tried to run it again and this strange behavior came up. Is there something wrong with Twitter or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Obviously the twitter api returns 50: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place and twitter4j passes the same. Simply stop processing at Position 10 ...

Comment: Twitter4j though claims to return 10: http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/4.0.4/twitter4j/api/TrendsResources.html#getPlaceTrends-int- and I'm sure I've called this method and it return 10 before.

Comment: So you proved twitter4j wrong. And what now ? File a bug or implement a workaround.